# Generate a bar code for the sharepoint list item Id, is this possible

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have an Assets SharePoint list. And using Power Apps , i want to generate a barcode which represents the Item Id when creating a new list item inside the Assets list, then save the bar code back to SharePoint.. can i achieve this using power apps?